# With Firebase Hosting how do I turn off bundling and minification?

Tags: javascript, firebase, bundling-and-minification

I am pleased with how quickly I can get my AngularJS and Firebase app deployed to Firebase Hosting, but it appears that local CSS and JavaScript files are bundled and minified as part of executing $firebase deploy

I would like to debug the JavaScript after deploying. How do I turn off bundling and minification as part of the deploy?

Comment: This is a legitimate question - why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>We're currently in beta and this is something we will be implementing soon but I'm afraid at this time it's not possible to turn off the minification and bundling on deploy.</strike>

We've just removed the minification step from the processing we do on the uploaded files so if you redeploy this should be working for you. Because of the way we handle caching, you might need to make a change to the html files that link to the scripts (even just a trivial whitespace change) before they reflect the changes.