# Firebase is not recognized in an app built using Marionette-Require-Boilerplate

Tags: marionette, firebase

I'm using the "Marionette-Require-Boilerplate"  (https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate) to build my app, which also uses Firebase and FirebaseSimpleLogin.  They are working fine in 'development' mode, but when it's time to minify it into 'Production' mode using Grunt and running in the browser, the minified version will have trouble finding the Firebase libraries, spitting out an error saying firebase is not defined.  Both the Firebase and FirebaseSimpleLogin libs have been included in the config file as followed:

```
paths:{
  "firebase"              : "../libs/firebase",
  "firebase-simple-login" : "../libs/firebase-simple-login",
  "backbone-firebase"     : "../libs/backbone-firebase",
}

shim: {
  "firebase": {
    "exports": "Firebase"
   },
   "firebase-simple-login": {
     "exports": "FirebaseSimpleLogin"
   },
   "backbone-firebase": {
     "deps": ["backbone", "firebase"],
     "exports": "backbone-firebase"
   }
}
```

It seems like the Boilerplate is minifying the code using Almond.js in 'production mode', but I'm not sure how that's affecting it. I tried including the Firebase libs in the 'path' variable in Grunt.js, but that didn't do anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

-Tony

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237034/with-firebase-hosting-how-do-i-turn-off-bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Firebase Support Team in solving the problem.  The solution is to remove the "exports" from the "backbone-firebase" shim as there's no such thing as "backbone-firebase"; it is part of the "Backbone" namespace, e.g. Backbone.Firebase.Colection.  Require.js was looking for something that is called "backbone-firebase" while non exists.  Once the "exports" is removed, Require.js works correctly during the minification.

```
shim: {
  "firebase": {
    "exports": "Firebase"
   },
   "firebase-simple-login": {
     "exports": "FirebaseSimpleLogin"
   },
   "backbone-firebase": {
     "deps": ["backbone", "firebase"]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be minifying the already minified Firebase sources - that will cause trouble. You should skip minification for firebase.js (and simple login).